# std::future in simple words?

Tags: c++, std-future

I saw the uses of `std::future` in the program written in C++. So, I quickly went to lookup what is is: [std::future](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) and got a quite complicated answer for me.

Can someone put it in simple words for a 6 years old kid? I have an understanding level of a 6 years old kid...

Just a small definition with a minimal use case will work for me. Let me know if it is too much to ask and I'll take back my question.

Comment: An `std::future` is an object which will *eventually* contain a value, but might not contain one yet.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future it is already explained clear enough in the official docs. With the examples.

Comment: Explaining `std::future` "for a 6 years old kid" may require too much guessing on our end.   All we know is that common explanations are insufficient for you, but we don't know in what way they are insufficient.  Have you read cppreference?   Have you seen an example?

Comment: std::future comes with multithreading and to summarize the final lesson of learncpp.com (https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/appendix-c-the-end/)  : Threading is powerful, but it introduces additional complexity, and a lot of room for additional errors. Therefore, I wouldn’t recommend starting here.. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `std::future<T>` is a handle to a result of work which is [potentially] not, yet, computed. You can imagine it as the receipt you get when you ask for work and the receipt is used to get the result back. For example, you may bring a bike to bike store for repair. You get a receipt to get back your bike. While the work is in progress (the bike being repaired) you can go about other business. Eventually, when the work is supposed to be done you ask for the result (the repaired bike) and [potentially] wait until the result is delivered.

`std::future<T>` is a general mechanism to receive result. It doesn't prescribe how the requested work is actually executed.

Answer (score 10):

There is a quite simple example on the cppreference page you linked. Slightly modified:

```
std::future<int> f = std::async(std::launch::async, []{
    // long calculation
    return /* some result */;
});
/* do some other stuff */
int result = f.get();
```

`std::async` with the `std::launch::async` flag runs a function (here a lambda) asynchronously (in another thread). It returns a `std::future`, which will *eventually*, when that function finishes, contain an `int` value.

While that function is running, we can go on and `/* do some other stuff */`.

When we need the result, we call `f.get()` which waits until the `int` value is available, meaning until the asynchronous function has finished, and then gives it to us. The value `f.get()` gives us is the function's return value which `std::async` stored in the `std::future` after the function returned.

Instead of `std::async` it may also be used with threads via `std::promise` or `std::packaged_task`.

Answer (score 4):

`std::future` is used only in multithreaded programs. Such programs use threads, which can be thought of as mutually independent subprograms, to perform some tasks. For a 6-years child, this would be like when several people do something independently to achieve some task, e.g. mommy buys tickets *while* daddy books a hotel. Now, these "threads", "workers", "subprograms" need to communicate to share / transfer some data securely. The problem is that since they are completely independent, one needs a mechanism with which the "producer" of the information can either send it to the "consumer" or communicate its failure to produce the data; similarly, the "consumer" or "receiver" must have a secure, reliable way to tell whether a) the data from another  thread is ready b) receive the data and c) receive the error signal should the "producer" fail to produce the data.

One method of providing  such synchronization mechanism is a **promise-future** pair. They always go in pairs - if you can see `std::future` without `std::promise`, it's because the latter has been hidden from you, but it's somewhere. `std::promise` is used by the producer to set (and "send") the data, whereas `std::future` is used by "consumer" to receive it. If the producer cannot fulfil the contract, that is, if it cannot produce or "satisfy" the promise with the data, it may satisfy it with an exception, which is a C++ method of telling that something has gone wrong. Then, the "consumer" will receive this exception instead of data via its `std::future`.

In summary:
`std::future` is an object used in multithreaded programming to receive  data or an exception from a different thread; it is one end of a single-use, one-way communication channel between two threads,  `std::promise` object being the other end. Using the promise-future pattern, you have a guarantee that your inter-thread communication is free of common errors specific to multithreaded programs, like race conditions or accessing already freed memory, which are very common if the threads "talk to each other" using methods designed for single-threaded programs, like when function (=thread) arguments are being passed by reference.